# Large Bitmap on Delphi

Tags: delphi, graphics, bitmap

I want to create large Bitmap with code

```
  LargeBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    LargeBmp.Width := 1000; // fine 
    LargeBmp.Height := 15000; // XP - EOutOfResources, Not enough memory, Win 7 - works fine
    ...
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LargeBmp);
  end;
```

This code raises an `EOutOfResources` exception with message "Not enough memory" on Windows XP but works fine in Windows 7.

What is wrong? Why *Not enough memory*? It's only 60 MB.

Comment: I assume you mean `LargeBmp.Height := 15000;`? If I change code to that this works OK with Delphi XE2 on Win 7/64

Comment: @GerryColl - Also works in Delphi 6 under XP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the pixel format like this:

```
LargeBmp.PixelFormat := pf24Bit;
```

I had the same problem several times and that always solved it.

Comment: As Darthman points out this relocates your bitmap from limited GDI memory to the user memory of your app, which can be up to 2 gb.

Answer (score 6):

As was discussed already, if you don't set the pixel format Windows will see it as a device-dependent bitmap. When you set the pixel format you create a DIB (device-independent bitmap).  This means it's independent of the display device (graphics card).

I've had this same problem, and wanted to point out that pf24bit is not the only option. In the Graphics unit, you also have:

```
TPixelFormat = (pfDevice, pf1bit, pf4bit, pf8bit, pf15bit, pf16bit, pf24bit, pf32bit, pfCustom);
```

For a project I'm working on, I found the 8 bit option worked the best for what I needed, since I had a very large bitmap (high resolution), but limited colors (I was creating the whole bitmap from some simple code).

So try out a few others, other than just pf24bit, to find what's optimal for your production environment.  I saved quite a bit of internal memory with the pf8bit option.

Answer (score 5):

Created bitmaps (by default) is stored in some buffer. That buffer's size depends on videodriver, os and God knows what else. 
This buffer can be pretty small (about 20-25mb) and if you will try to create more, it will fail.

To avoid this try to create DIB instead of TBitmap, or try to change `Pixelformat` to `pf24bit`. This will tell system to create Bitmap in user's memory instead of GDI buffer.

Now, why it not fails in win7 you ask? Ok, probably cause there is no GDI, but GDI+ and Direct2D uses in win 7 instead. Maybe other driver's version, dunno.

Comment: By default `PixelFormat` is `pfDevice` that means that _The bitmap is stored as a device-dependent bitmap._ You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183561(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: "probably cause there is no GDI, but GDI+" what do u mean ? GDI+ is just a DLL, working on top of GDI,. that u can distribute with your application, and it was created in WinXP times. But now it is obsolete and video-card-accelerated API's likle Direct 2D are trated "rught way". So how came Win7 lacks GDI ???